# ayuda con instalacion de SQL Server!

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Hola siempre que trato de instalar sql server en mi laptop me sale el siguiente error ¡ayuda porfavor!**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el error dice que tenes instalada una version mas nueva

Comment: Parece que tienes algo instalado. Primero desinstala toda la versión que hayas instalado. Segunda instalación de SQL Server 2017 Developer.

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853016

Answer (score 0):

Intenta reparar la instalación por si tuvieras algún fallo en los archivo.. cuando reparas una instalación:

- Se reemplazan todos los archivos que se hayan perdido o dañado.
- Se reemplazan todas las claves del **Registro** que se hayan perdido o
  dañado.
- Todos los valores de configuración que se hayan perdido o que no sean
  válidos se establecen en los valores predeterminados.

La otra posibilidad, como te dicen arriba, es que ya tenga algo instalado de las otras veces que has intentado instalar el ***SGBD***, te recomiendo personalmente (porque a mi también me pasó en su día) borrar **TODO** lo referente a **sql server**, entra en el registro (***regedit***) y busca cualquier clave sobre **sql server** y borralas. Después intenta instalar todo de nuevo.